# max value from sqlite giving wrong result not getting correct value

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, output, max

I have written one query which gives me result but not the exact result which I want.
For example I have more than 5000 record something but it giving me 999 as a result.
My DB Query is:

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select max(id) from table", null);
```

output is:
999 (wrong)

Comment: try SELECT count(*) FROM table"

Comment: The query is doing exactly you want it to do. Out of all the `id` in the table, `999` should be the maximum id. Try `select count(*) from table where id>999`. You will get `0`

Comment: Thanx a lot count gives me the result, which is total no of records and my id column is having bigger value than count value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been max qyery on String column

`Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select max(id) from table", null);`

So It is not storing in **integer**, rather than storing in string format **TEXT**

So if we have String format then the number are sorted in different way.

When I doing max query it resulting the max number not max id.

> For Example
>
> **if i have 0 to 4000 record it return 999**
>
> **if i have 0 to 40000 record it return 9999**

so this is troubling and giving me wrong result